# NORM PPF function throws error on a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scipy, apache-spark-sql

norm.ppf function works on single value.

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
pct_5 = norm.ppf(0.008)  
print(pct_5)
```

When I use it on a column; it throws me error.
I have tried two methods

1. Applying the function directly on a column

```
df1 = df.withColumn('ppf_col',norm.ppf(col(col1)))
```

```
Error : ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool
```

2. Using a UDF

   ```
   def ppf():
        return (norm.ppf(col('col1')))

    my_udf = udf(ppf,FloatType())    
    df = df1.withColumn('ppf_col',my_udf(col('col1')))    
    df.show()
   ```

```
Error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1780.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 76, d2-td-cdh.boigroup.net, executor 14): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 361, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 236, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 163, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 64, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 577, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Note : I have scipy version 1.2.0; it stills throws error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

I want to understand why it doesnt work on a column
col1 values:

```
7.999999999999999E-4
0.013793103448275862
0.013612808415190657
                 1.0
                 1.0
 0.05449976056308704
                 1.0
```

Comment: Have you installed scipy on your workers too? I believe that's the issue. It's not sufficient to install scipy on the driver, otherwise your UDFs will not work.

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about it, but you should probably set the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` parameter of your Spark application to the path where your environment with scipy and all the other packages is located, e.g. `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/my/env`. Also, maybe this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-get-the-python-environment-of-all-spark-cluster-nodes-2642075e7772) could he helpful.

Comment: I have installed scipy 1.5 and numpy 1.14.5 on my system...Still I face the same issue... The column I am using is having a double datatype....Is there any additional parameters that needs to be passed?

Comment: Why is it converting column to a boolen..?

Comment: The first method you proposed is completely wrong: you cannot use a scipy (on a Python module) function on a Pyspark dataframe column; you need to incapsulate in a UDF or a Pandas UDF. To do that, you need to have scipy installed in ALL your workers, not only your driver.

Comment: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

Comment: python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

/usr/local/bin
/home/cdsw/Package/Python-3.9.6/Lib/site-packages
/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python36.zip
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/home/cdsw/.conda/envs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cdsw-1.0.0-py3.6.egg
/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python

Comment: There are several paths mentioned here...I was just wandering if im setting the right path?